# How to separate messages sent through a Network Stream

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have a network stream for a simple TCP server/client (I'm following a tutorial), sending/receiving works fine. My question is that is there any way to "clear" the network stream once the data has been read, so that the next "message" sent isn't appended to the end of the previous message?

Comment: No. Any other question?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? TCP is a stream-oriented protocol, which means there's no concept of message or packet boundaries. It's just a continuous homogeneous stream of bytes.

Comment: sending/receiving separate messages between a client/server: eg: the client sends a message to the server, the server sends a message in response.

Comment: @BnMcG How about possible alternatives?. a) prepand the length of the message b) A seperator between messages...

Comment: @BnMcG Post your code - the question makes no sense without it...

Comment: Yeah I gave it some thought after finding out you can't just clear the stream and I'll give separators a go!

Comment: You are assuming that old data is appended. This assumption should seem absurd to you. Why would the API be implemented that way? This should make you think that something else is going on that you don't know about. Therefore, don't ask about "clearing" the stream. Ask, how you properly read from a TCP connection. (And that would be a duplicate question.)

Comment: @usr `You are assuming that old data is appended.` OP sees that newer data is appended.

Comment: @L.B I was referring to the statement `that the next "message" sent isn't appended to the end of the previous message`. It seems I was a little too short with my comment.